# asp.net controls for MAP based Applications

Tags: asp.net

I am new to stackoverflow, I am creating an .net web map applications similar to google maps.
But my 1st requirement is to create my own map. please suggest tools to create shapefiles,index files and dbfiles.

2nd requirement is that i need to know controls in asp.net for implementing it.

I have a jpg image of my map can i use that image as my map or do i need to create the shape files for this. I want to include all the features shown in google map in my application.

Note .net 3.5 framework is where i have to implement this application. And also i can not use any existing map such as bing, google maps.

Comment: ImageMap can be handy in some cases, take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Look into ESRI's ArcInfo and Spacial Analyst tools. We used to do generate our own maps, but it was fairly time consuming (but this was some 10+ yrs ago). They have probably made it faster these days. It sounds like you may have some knowledge of arcview (shapefiles, db, indx), but that will not do what you need.

Comment: Thank You very much Edward i shall look onto ESRI's ArcInfo and Spacial Analyst tools.

Comment: Edward I have my map in form of a jpg image.
Now i want to use that image as my map, with all the controls possible such as
marking areas on the map etc using asp.net.
So when i want to mark something on the map i also want to capture the area where a comment has been marked so that any other who sees the map next time can see the comments marked. In short i want to know how to capture the information about different area in my jpg map in form of x,y coordinate of that area. Thanks in advance.